# return python calculation result to excel vba function

Tags: python, vba

I have a question about calling a Python script in my Excel VBA function.
For instance, in my Excel VBA function, I have: `abc(x,y,z)`. In this function, I will pass `x`,`y`,`z` to my Python script as input. Python output will then return calculation result to my `abc()` function. What I want to achieve is as follows:

```
    function abc(x,y,z)
    ' here x, y, z is the input that will pass to Python
    ' then we call python scripts here with the return value h
    < call Python here>
    abc=h
    end function
```

My question is:

1. How to pass `x`,`y`,`z` to Python scripts?
2. How to give my return value `h` to `abc()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass a value from VBA to python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831771/how-do-you-pass-a-value-from-vba-to-python)

Comment: If you look to the right below the adds you will see similar questions with answers.  I would encourage your to look at those

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return result from Python to Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516875/return-result-from-python-to-vba)