# Return result from Python to Vba

Tags: python, vba

I'm using a VBA code that calls a python script. I can send a parameter to my python script and reading it using `sys.argv[1]`.

In the python code I have a function that takes the given argument and return a value.

Please how can I get the return value in VBA?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider using VBA Shell's `StdOut` to capture a stream of the output lines. Be sure to have the Python script print to screen the value:

**Python**

```
...
print(outputval)
```

**VBA** *(`s` below would be string output)*

```vb
Public Sub PythonOutput()

    Dim oShell As Object, oCmd As String
    Dim oExec As Object, oOutput As Object
    Dim arg As Variant
    Dim s As String, sLine As String

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    arg = "somevalue"
    oCmd = "python ""C:\Path\To\Python\Script.py""" & " " & arg

    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(oCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbNewLine
    Wend

    Debug.Print s

    Set oOutput = Nothing: Set oExec = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Credit**

Script borrowed from [@bburns.km](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243392/bburns-km), non-accepted answer, from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600510/1422451)

Comment: This works, but it is extremely slow when there are many lines of output to iterate over. Do you know why it is so slow?

Comment: @jippyjoe4, all depends on your use case and what you mean by *extremely slow*. Please ask a new question if you need help.

Comment: Nice! This works in VB6 as well when many other solutions would not work. I had to first add "Windows Script Host Object Model" under Project -> References.