# how to pass variable from python to access vba

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I want to retrieve the variable value from a python script and use that in my vba code in Access. What I have so far is a button that runs a bat file with shell command. The bat file runs the python script and the variable "output" is printed to screen. I want to grab that "output" variable value for use in my Access project.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return result from Python to Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516875/return-result-from-python-to-vba)

Comment: So Olvin provided the right idea. I am unable to get the arg value to pass to the python script though.