# problem with running a Python function from a macro in excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have the following Python script named 'func.py':

```py
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    return np.array([[x+y, x], [x-y, y]])
```

and I would like to use the function `func` with a macro in Excel, I wrote this code for the macro:

```vb
Sub CallPythonFunction()
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim result As Variant
    
    ' Get the input values from Excel cells
    x = Range("A1").Value
    y = Range("B1").Value
    
    ' Call the Python function using xlwings
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    result = RunPython("import func; func.func(" & x & ", " & y & ")")
    
    ' Write the result to Excel
    Range("C1").Value = result(1, 1)
    Range("C2").Resize(result.Rows.Count, result.Columns.Count).Value = result.Value
    
End Sub
```

However, it does not work. When the cells A1 and B1 in excel are filled with the numbers 1 and 3 respectively, I got an error message 'error 13, type mismatch'.

Comment: Maybe `x` and `y` are being passed as strings? Convert them to ints either in the VBA or in Python...

Comment: `RunPython` [does not allow you to return values](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/vba.html#function-arguments-and-return-values).

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516875/return-result-from-python-to-vba

Comment: Could I suggest giving [xlOil](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/) a look?  (Disclaimer: i wrote it) There is no need to write the VBA stub as it can call the python directly.  That said, xlwings can do a similar trick with the [func](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/udfs.html) decorator.  If you really want to call from VBA, then you can call the declared function with `Application.Run`.   Appreciate this is a bit brief, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Thanks @stevecu, I would like to try but I do not see any doc about the installation.

Comment: Try [here](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/xlOil_Python/GettingStarted.html#getting-started)